# Writing regex code for a string to occur before two others

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex search code for the following idea -

`sentence one BEFORE {sentence2 AND sentence 3}`

The 3 phrases, `sentence one`, `sentence2` and `sentence 3` are provided to the code separately.

I can easily do it as -

`re.search(sentence one.*?sentence2) AND re.search(sentence one.*?sentence 3)`,

but I was thinking if there was a way to express the original idea within one regex. I am using Python.

**EDIT -** Just wanted to mention that it is not necessary that all phrases always exist. To clarify, the resultant regex will be a rule. If either of `sentence2` or `sentence 3` exist in the file, it should satisfy it, and if both exist, then too. If `sentence one` does not exist in the file, then it will be useless.

Comment: Use alternation as: `r'sentence one.*?(sentence2|sentence2)'`

Comment: Lets call them s1, s2 and s3 for brevity `s1.*(?:s2.*s3|s3.*s2)`

Comment: Need some clarification on `Just wanted to mention that it is not necessary that all phrases always exist`. Also provide few examples.

Comment: @anubhava, clarified as asked

Comment: `(sentence2|sentence2)` means match either of 2 keywords

Answer (score 1):

I think the clearest way is to do it using control flow as you have.

You could do something along the lines of

```
sentence 1 then (sentence 2 then sentence 3 or sentence 3 then sentence 2)
```

i.e.

```
sentence one.*?(?:sentence two.*?sentence three|sentence three.*?sentence two)
```

but obviously this is much less readable and not generalisable.

Note that all of this presumes that the sentences do not intersect.

Comment: please look at the edit. Your answer assumes that all phrases exist, right?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. The point of a regex is to match the pattern. If the pattern doesn't occur it won't return a match.

I suggest giving some example matches to explain what you mean.

Comment: i have clarified, please have a look

Comment: So you mean you want a match if sentence one is in the document and either sentence two or sentence three (or both) are in the document?

Comment: could you update your answer in context with the above comments?